# jQuery height animate causes background color to be ignored

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tkg7/5/), after animation on the second click background of the `<ul>` is not appearing any more, however inspecting the `CSS` in firebug shows the style is being applied. What is the problem ?

EDIT: The red background disappears after click on any `<li>`.

The relevant code:

HTML

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="selectCover">
    <button>Transfer</button>
    <ul style="position: absolute; left: -34.5px; top:-15px; display:none;" value="0040346781">
        <li class="selected">CANCEL</li>
        <li data-branch="SJ">SJ</li>
        <li data-branch="SYI">SYI</li>
        <li data-branch="SZ">SZ</li>
        <li data-branch="SY">SY</li>
        <li data-branch="SE">SE</li>
        <li data-branch="SG">SG</li>
        <li data-branch="SD">SD</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.selectCover ul{
   background: red;
}
li.selected{
    background: green;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.selectCover').click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown(100,function(){
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).slideUp(100);
            $(this).off('mouseleave');
        });
    });
});

$('.selectCover li').click(function(e){
    $.post('x').done(function(){
        console.log($(e.target).attr('data-branch'));
        $(e.target).parent().attr('currsel',$(e.target).attr('data-branch'))
    });
    $(e.target).parent().animate({height : 0});
});
```

Comment: Please post relevant code in question

Comment: A. Wolff I am doing it now

Comment: @Dimt, do you want to hide list after selecting any item from it or it should be fine if it is visible and will get hide after mouse leaves it?

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar after selecting item from the list would be better, because I have more underlying logic, simply the list is populated from ajax response, which should be reflected after each item click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript should look like this:

```
$('.selectCover').find('button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown(100,function(){
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).slideUp(100);
        });
    });
});

$('.selectCover li').click(function(e){
    $.post('x').done(function(){
        console.log($(e.target).attr('data-branch'));
        $(e.target).parent().attr('currsel',$(e.target).attr('data-branch'))
    });
    $(this).parent().slideUp(100);
});
```

There are 2 problems in your code:

There was a problem with your click events. Both click listeners where triggered because they were both clicked when you click an "li" element. This was caused by the click event on the complete container, and the click events on the sepperate "li" elements. Clicking an "li" element would also cause a click event on the complete container (thous your first declared listener would trigger again).

The second problem is that you put the height to the element to 0. slideDown() doesn't seem to update the DOM height value correctly, so the background gets drawn with 0 height.

I put the first click event on the button so it will not trigger when you click an "li" element.

here's your new fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/64zUr/

Comment: Or whatever you want, at least now you have the problem

Comment: ps. I don't see this bit of css in your question but I did see it in your fiddle.

Comment: the red background is being ignored after animation, I've updated the question, sorry.

Comment: The red background disappears after click on any <li>

Comment: I've deliberately used animation because I had problem with slideUp() which was addressed in another question  [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426269/jquery-slideup-interupted-by-ajax-done-dom-update)

Comment: No problem, you can change it back to the animation but I think I should have a look in your other question as well. It should work when used correctly.

Comment: Oh, I've noticed the problem now, this is possibly relevant to my other question.  I will try to apply your solution into the application. Will let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit below code.

Here you have tried using hide or slidup, but it was creating problem. To tackle this hide / slidup problem, you have used `$(e.target).parent().animate({height : 0});`, which is removing background color.

When you select item from the list, that click event getting propogated to selectCover div and hence it is becoming visible again when you are hiding or makind slideup.

please follow below code with both the problems resolved, and see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tkg7/14/)

```
$('.selectCover li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent propogation of click event to parent div
    $.post('x').done(function(){
        console.log($(e.target).attr('data-branch'));
        $(e.target).parent().attr('currsel',$(e.target).attr('data-branch'))
    });
    $(e.target).parent().slideUp(100); // removed animation as it will remove bg color, so using slideup only
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which indicates the underlying problem. Will let you know when I get my solution working.